# The specified child already has a parent Exception Error

Tags: java, android, view

I am currently having a problem with adding views to parents. I have no idea how to solve this. I have looked at other answers with the same exception but nothing was able to help me.

Here is my code:

```
int countdown = 0;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
TableRow tr1;
TableRow tr2;
TextView tv;
protected void createNullUI() {
    tr1 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tr2 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Ooops, it looks like the user you were searching for does not exist... You will be redriced back to our homepage shortly =)");
    tv.setMaxLines(2);
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setSingleLine(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress, null, false);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         public void run() {
                    //set up the count down timer
             mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress" + countdown
                            + millisUntilFinished);
                    countdown++;
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    countdown++;
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();

            TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            tr1.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
            tr2.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

            tr1.addView(tv);
            tr2.addView(mProgressBar);
            ((ViewGroup)tr1.getParent()).removeView(tr1);
            ((ViewGroup)tr2.getParent()).removeView(tr2);
            tableScrollView.addView(tr1); // <--- Error here
            tableScrollView.addView(tr2);
         }  
    });
}
```

Exception:

```
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3365)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3236)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3181)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3157)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at com.tabcards.android.Search$2.run(Search.java:197)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
08-30 02:44:37.446: E/AndroidRuntime(17698):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit: even something simple as this throws the error:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                tv1.setText("null input");
                tableScrollView.addView(tv1);
```

tell me if you need the code of the whole class.

Edit: whole class:

```
//removed imports & package


public class Search extends ActionBarActivity {
TableLayout tableScrollView;
String value;
JSONObject jObject;

private Bitmap profilepic;
private Drawable bgpic;
TableLayout tr;
TableRow trcard;
TableLayout tlcard;
int bgcolor = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    tr = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(0);
    // bgpic.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("id");
    }
    trcard = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tlcard = new TableLayout(getBaseContext());
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle(value);
    tableScrollView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableScrollView);
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jObject = getJson("http://www.tabcards.com/req/androidapi/L2o30H8JlFMtFYHW3KLxkts20ztc5Be6Z6m6v315/json/"
                    + value);
            if (jObject != null) {

                try {

                    if (!jObject.getString("profilepic").equals("")) {
                        profilepic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(
                                jObject.getString("profilepic"))
                                .openConnection().getInputStream());
                    }
                    if (!jObject.getString("bg").equals("")) {
                        if (jObject.getString("bg").toString()
                                .startsWith("#")) {
                            System.out.println(jObject.getString("bg"));
                            bgcolor = Color.parseColor(jObject
                                    .getString("bg"));
                        } else {
                            profilepic = BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeStream(new URL(jObject
                                            .getString("bg"))
                                            .openConnection()
                                            .getInputStream());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            createUI(jObject);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //TextView tv1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                //tv1.setText("null input");
                //tableScrollView.addView(tv1);

                //createNullUI();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent returnBtn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(returnBtn);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    System.out.println("complete");
}

int countdown = 0;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
TableRow tr1;
TableRow tr2;
TextView tv;
protected void createNullUI() {
    tr1 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tr2 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Ooops, it looks like the user you were searching for does not exist... You will be redriced back to our homepage shortly =)");
    tv.setMaxLines(2);
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setSingleLine(false);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress, null, false);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         public void run() {
                    //set up the count down timer
             mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress" + countdown
                            + millisUntilFinished);
                    countdown++;
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    countdown++;
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(countdown);
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();

            TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            tr1.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
            //tr2.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams1);

            tr1.addView(tv);
            tr2.addView(mProgressBar);
            ((ViewGroup)tr1.getParent()).removeView(tr1);
            ((ViewGroup)tr2.getParent()).removeView(tr2);
            tableScrollView.addView(tr1);
            //tableScrollView.addView(tr2);
         }

    });




}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void createUI(JSONObject jObject) throws JSONException {
    int absIndex = 0;
    System.out.println(jObject.getString("bg") + "createUI");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        if (bgcolor != -1) {
            System.out.println("color: " + bgcolor);
            tr.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
        } else if (bgpic != null) {
            tr.setBackground(bgpic);
        }
    }
    boolean last = false;

    String lastString = WhoIsLast(jObject);
    System.out.println(lastString);
    String name = jObject.getString("name");
    String facebook = jObject.getString("facebook");
    String twitter = jObject.getString("twitter");
    String phone = jObject.getString("phone");
    String email = jObject.getString("email");
    if (name != "") {
        insertElement(name, "name", absIndex++, profilepic, true, false);
    }
    ;

    if (!facebook.equals("")) {
        if (facebook.equals(lastString)) {
            last = true;
        }
        insertElement(facebook, "facebook", absIndex,
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.facebook), false, last);
        absIndex += 2;
    }
    if (!twitter.equals("")) {
        if (twitter.equals(lastString)) {
            last = true;
        }
        insertElement(twitter, "twitter", absIndex,
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.twitter), false, last);
        absIndex += 2;
    }
    if (!phone.equals("")) {
        if (phone.equals(lastString)) {
            last = true;
        }
        insertElement(phone, "phone", absIndex,
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.phone), false, last);
        absIndex += 2;
    }
    if (!email.equals("")) {
        if (email.equals(lastString)) {
            last = true;
        }
        insertElement(email, "email", absIndex,
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.email), false, true);
        absIndex += 2;
    }

    trcard.setBackground(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_card/* abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light */));
    trcard.addView(tlcard);
    tr.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.dividerVertical };
    TypedArray typedArray = getApplicationContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs);
    Drawable divider = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
    typedArray.recycle();

    tableRowParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
    trcard.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
    tlcard.setDividerDrawable(divider);

    tlcard.setDividerPadding(4);

    tableScrollView.addView(trcard);

}

private String WhoIsLast(JSONObject j) throws JSONException {
    if (j.getString("facebook").equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    if (j.getString("twitter").equals("")) {
        return "facebook";
    }
    if (j.getString("email").equals("")) {
        return "twitter";
    }
    if (j.getString("phone").equals("")) {
        return "email";
    }

    return "";
}

/*
 * private void createMainImage() { LayoutInflater inflater =
 * (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); View
 * newRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);
 * newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
 * TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 * TextView dataTextView = (TextView) newRow
 * .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView); dataTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 * ImageView iv = (ImageView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 * DisplayMetrics metrics =
 * getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); int width =
 * metrics.widthPixels; int height = metrics.heightPixels;
 * iv.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(profilepic,
 * width-300, width-300, true), iv));
 * 
 * tableScrollView.addView(newRow, 0); }
 */

private void insertElement(String data, String key, int i, Bitmap bm,
        boolean flag, boolean b) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View newRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    AutoResizeTextview dataTextView = (AutoResizeTextview) newRow
            .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    dataTextView.setText("\t " + data);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    newRow.setId(i);
    newRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView tv = null;
            ArrayList<View> allViewsWithinMyTopView = getAllChildren(view);
            for (View child : allViewsWithinMyTopView) {
                if (child instanceof TextView) {
                    tv = (TextView) child;

                }
            }
            String prefix = "";
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case 1:
                prefix = "https://www.facebook.com/";
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(prefix + tv.getText().toString()));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                break;
            case 2:
                prefix = "https://www.twitter.com/";
                Intent browserIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(prefix
                                + tv.getText().toString()
                                        .replace("%20", "")));
                startActivity(browserIntent2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:"
                                + tv.getText().toString()
                                        .replace("%20", "")));
                startActivity(phoneIntent);
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"
                        + tv.getText().toString()));
                emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(emailIntent);
                break;
            }

        }
    });

    View v = new View(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(15, 111, 111, 111));

    dataTextView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int sf = 1;
    if (i == 0) {
        sf = 2;
        dataTextView.setShadowLayer(3, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        dataTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    if (bm == null) {
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        iv.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, bm.getWidth() / 2 * sf,
                        bm.getWidth() / 2 * sf, true),
                dataTextView.getMeasuredHeight() * sf,
                dataTextView.getMeasuredHeight() * sf, true), iv, key));
    }

    if (flag) {
        dataTextView.setTextSize(40);

        tableScrollView.addView(newRow, i);
    } else {
        tlcard.addView(newRow, i - 1);
        if (!b) {
            tlcard.addView(v, i);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean useLoop(String[] arr, String targetValue) {
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (s.equals(targetValue))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject getJson(String url) {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    // HTTP
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    // Read response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString().replace("[", "");
        System.out.println(result);

        if (result.equals("CARD NOT FOUND\n")) {
            System.out.println(result);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    // Convert string to object
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.replace("]", ""));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return jsonObject;

}

private ArrayList<View> getAllChildren(View v) {

    if (!(v instanceof ViewGroup)) {
        ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
        viewArrayList.add(v);
        return viewArrayList;
    }

    ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {

        View child = vg.getChildAt(i);

        ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
        viewArrayList.add(v);
        viewArrayList.addAll(getAllChildren(child));

        result.addAll(viewArrayList);
    }
    return result;
}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView iv,
        String key) {
    if (key == "email" || key == "facebook" || key == "twitter"
            || key == "phone") {
        return bitmap;
    }
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int radius = Math.min(h / 2, w / 2);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + 8, h + 8, Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(output);
    c.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);

    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 4, 4, p);
    p.setXfermode(null);
    p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStrokeWidth(1);

    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);

    return output;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: whole class would help

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin ok will do in the morning. Does it help that the icon does not change even when it is replaced with another image?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Ok, I added the whole class. Also, if it helps, when I save & run the app, it says it is already deployed and that it does not need to reinstall(?). I don't know if that affects it and I would also like to ask you if you know a fix.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Never mind, I found the source of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It was the fact that I did not run the code in a UI thread...